# ASP.NET Server Image browser

Tags: asp.net, file-browser

I am developing e-Shop with ASP.NET.
In admin panel when moderator wants to define image for products I want to let him to upload a ZIP file that contains all his desired images.
I did that but now I am looking for a control or sample that let user watch and choose images from a folder (in server).
I look for Image borwser.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of [jQuery](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) plugins to browse images. You can also create folder browser using methods of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` (to get list of folders and files) and `GridView` ([Data controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ImageBrowser.aspx).)